# apt-get source: Unknown command "source"

Tags: debian, apt, source

Following [this tutorial](http://doc.owncloud.org/server/5.0/admin_manual/installation/installation_others.html#lighttpd-configuration), I'm stuck a this line:

```
$ apt-get source lighttpd
Unknown command "source"
aptitude 0.6.8.2
```

Why does my apt-get/aptitude does not support this command?

I don't know if this has something to do with this, but my `sources.list` did not contain any `deb-src` lines. After adding this, `apt-get build-dep lighttpd` did run run without any errors.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An error message from `apt-get` wouldn't mention `aptitude`. Did you alias `apt-get` to `aptitude` and forget about it? It may be time to

```
unalias apt-get
```

Comment: If you want to do this temporarily without removing the alias, you can also just use `\apt-get` instead of `apt-get`.